# How do I make my iOS settings bundle only work in a debug build?

Tags: ios, build, settings

I have a few different build configurations (debug, testing, release), and I want a settings bundle ONLY when debugging.

How do I accomplish this? I don't see a way to direct it at specific build configs :(

Answer (score -1):

You need to create 3 schemes. For each scheme then you can tune the params.
For example you can define a DEBUG flag for your debug scheme and then use that flag during debugging. [Sorry I cant elaborate because your question is not very clear].

[Here](http://swwritings.com/post/2013-05-20-concurrent-debug-beta-app-store-builds) is a detailed post on how to create the schemes for your target.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know how to create schemes! What I am trying to do specifically is include the settings bundle ONLY in 2 of the 3 schemes. (Release should NOT have this settings bundle).

I don't see a way to exclude this file when building for release.